# Start service on timer start and each N seconds after

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

I use `OnUnitActive` property which will run each N secods using last activation time of service as starting point, but i want it always run once when timer started and use 'OnUnitActive' property after.

How can i force this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an extra directive `OnActiveSec=0s` to the `[Timer]` stanza.

The [systemd maintainer explains how this works](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4572#issuecomment-260014156).